# How to read large set of data as lazyarrays

Tags: uproot

I am trying to read a large set of data as lazyarrays doing the following:

```py
import uproot
import numpy as np

file_path = "~/data.root"
data = uproot.lazyarrays(file_path, "E")
hits = data['hits']
>>> <ChunkedArray [176 125 318 ... 76 85 51] at 0x7fb8612a8390>
np.array(hits)
>>> array([176, 125, 318, ...,  76,  85,  51], dtype=int32)
```

So as you can see, we can read 'hits' data as a lazzyarray and as an array without issues. But, when I try the same steps for a different branch, I get a ValueError. Here is how I proceed:

```py
data['hits.dom_id']
>>> ValueError: value too large
```

However, when I access 'hits.dom_id' using uproot.array() I get my data. Here is how I proceed:

```py
data2 = uproot.open(file_path)['E']['Evt']['hits']
data2['hits.dom_id'].array()
>>> <JaggedArray [[806451572 806451572 806451572 ... 809544061 809544061 809544061] [806451572 806451572 806451572 ... 809524432 809526097 809544061] [806451572 806451572 806451572 ... 809544061 809544061 809544061] ... [806451572 806451572 806451572 ... 809006037 809524432 809544061] [806451572 806451572 806451572 ... 809503416 809503416 809544058] [806451572 806465101 806465101 ... 809544058 809544058 809544061]] at 0x7fb886cbbbd0>
```

I have notice, but maybe this is just a coincidence, that whenever my data is in a JaggesArray format, uproot.lazyarrays() raises the same ValueError.

I might be doing something wrong here, could you please help?

Note: I don't think it's a RAM issue. I tried playing with the cache size, by using a cache size bigger than my data set and uproot.lazyarrays() still raised the ValueError.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueError: value too large` is the error message that `cachetools` emits when it can't put one array into cache. People hit this so often that I think I'll need to catch it and reemit it with a more informative message or maybe even enlarge the cache to make it fit. (Is that a terrible idea? I need to find a good default policy for caches.)

See the recent GitHub Issues—lazy arrays do have an implicit `basketcache`  (which is different from the `cache`). You might need to provide an explicit `basketcache` if any of your baskets are bigger than 1 MB (the default limit).

Comment: For the sake of completeness: just pass e.g. `  basketcache=uproot.cache.ThreadSafeArrayCache(20*1024**2)` as a parameter to `lazyarray()`

Comment: Or `ThreadSafeArrayCache("20 MB")`; the argument is either an integer number of bytes or a string data size with units.